# Print Maximum element of a 2D array C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I had this code working, it went through the array and printed out the largest number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int arr[2][5] ={{40,7,12,3,0},{10,2,30,9,8}};
int temp=0;

int main()
{
    for(int row=0; row>2; row++){
        for(int col=0; col>5; col++){
            if(arr[row][col]>temp)
            temp = arr[row][col];
            }

        }
        cout<<temp;
        return 0;
}
```

But now that I rewrote, I guess I did it wrong and I get output: 0 every run.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: `col>5` ==> `col<5`

Comment: row > 2 ? Given row is 0, It wont even start the loop.

Comment: Thank you both. I was careless about the signs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the values of row size and column size in the `for` loops, you can derive their sizes like this:

```
int rowsize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof (arr[0]);
int colsize = sizeof(arr)/(rowsize * sizeof (arr[0][0]));
```

Then your `for` loops can be changed to:

```
for(int row=0; row<rowsize; row++){
    for(int col=0; col<colsize; col++){
        if(arr[row][col]>temp)
            temp = arr[row][col];
    }
}
```

If you do this, you can increase the rows and cols of `arr` without having to change the code.